# Custom Search Image Child Safe

Tags: c#, ios, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I am using **Google Custom search API** in an app where a **kid** can **search images.** I want to make it child safe and **don't show explicit content**. I tried to find anything related to that on web and google custom search documents but was unable to find anything that worked.

There was a Filtering Adult Content with SafeSearch for which I query should contain safe parameter and I set it to high which means "Enables a stricter version of safe search." Found on [Google Documentations](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#safeSearchLevels.).

After adding safe option and setting it to high. I tried searching images for **"Hot"** keyword but I was still getting adult content.

Here's my query : 
 https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?cx=011234186204374308933:cqoplxwcsqq&key=AIzaSyBh0KqiD-19vCR7MicJFBOiwWgdCYH9OgE&q=Hot&start=1&searchType=image&safe=high&rights=cc_attribute%2ccc_publicdomain%2ccc_sharealike%2ccc_nonderived&fileType=%2bpng%2c%2bjpg

Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: Have you compared the result of safe=off vs safe=high? Probably Google just doesn't recognize some results are NSFW.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be difference adding safe or not atleast with Hot keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you aren't seen any difference between unfiltered and filtered with the word 'hot' is because none of the non-filtered results are considered 'adult content' according to Google's filtering.  If you use a more explicit term you will see larger differences.

Comment: yes but I am seeing this website http://www.kiddle.co (google search for kids) which is powered by google custom search and when I write Hot there are totally different and saferesults.

Comment: Hey You can try by replacing the inappropriate word too.

Comment: I did try with an inappropriate word and saw that the api worked as expected.  What word did you use and what result did you see?

Comment: I used the work "dick" and response contained vulgar pictures.